# Does HtmlUnit and jasmine-maven-plugin support HTML5 sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, htmlunit, jasmine-maven-plugin

I am trying to test a JavaScript function that uses HTML5 sessionStorage on jasmine-maven-plugin. Jasmine uses HtmlUnit to emulate a web browser.

The problem is that when the automated tests are running during maven build, it says:

> - Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.

I have tried this [How to deal with sessionStorage locally in FF (for testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428210/how-to-deal-with-sessionstorage-locally-in-ff-for-testing) and then I've got this error:

> - TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object in file: ...

But if I try to run Jasmine on a web page importing jasmine.js, the test works perfectly. 
I have tried this too [Can I access HTML5 storages using HTMLUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217182/can-i-access-html5-storages-using-htmlunit) , but without success.

An example of code that works on http://tryjasmine.com/ and not in jasmine-maven-plugin:

```
function alertItem(id) {
console.log("start");
var x = sessionStorage.getItem(id);
alert(x);
}

describe("sessionStorage test", function () {    
console = {
    log : function() {},
    error : function() {},
    warn : function() {}
};

var mockup = function() {
    var table = {};
    return {
        getItem: function(key) {
            return table[key];
        },
        setItem: function(key, value) {
            table[key] = value.toString();
        },
        removeItem: function(key) {
            table.pop();
        },      
        clear: function() {
            table = {};
        }
    };
}();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
    value: mockup
});


it("must work", function () {
    console.log("testing...");
    spyOn(sessionStorage, 'getItem').andReturn("my value");
    alertItem("id");
    expect(sessionStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kyle suggested, using sessionStorage on jasmine-maven-plugin with PhantomJS instead of HtmlUnit worked!

More information at: http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/phantomjs.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

HTMLUnit does not support many HTML5 features - while your browser does, this is why it will work in the browser but not as part of the build with HTMLUnit.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the answer. Do you know any maven plugin that runs jasmine without HTMLUnit? Or are HTMLUnit team  working to support HTML5?

Comment: I have submitted a bug on HTMLUnit sourceforge but they seems not to be working on it, because it includes jasmine maven: http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1413/

Comment: Support for using the jasmine-maven-plugin with PhantomJS instead of HtmlUnit was recently added. There is an example configuration here: http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/phantomjs.html